# How to configure Azure b2c Sign Up and Sign In using Username with MFA using Email or Phone and Unique Email/Phone and Custom field?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am exploring Azure AD B2C Scenario but XML policy and its technical terminology looks very complex for me.

I am configuring Azure AD B2C Policy for the existing system which is based on username and password.
Unique Username and UniqueId generated in the existing system.

So, I need to configure Azure AD B2C Sign Up and Sign In

- Before Sign Up need to make REST API Call to get uniqueId of Employee from other system
- Using Username Only
- Store EmployeeId in Azure B2C Directory while Sign up and need to check unique EmployeeId in the B2C directory
- MFA using Email or Phone with a username. Users can select either option.
- Password Reset with MFA Either using Email and Phone Number based on user preference
- Username discovery is possible or not not sure.

I am not sure this type of custom policy can be possible or not.

Is there any Azure B2C custom policy that has a similar kind of use flow or functionality?

I have referred [MFA Email or Phone](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone) Policy but don't know how to combine validation, username flow, and another scenario.

Any help or suggestion much appreciated Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do your 'username only sign-up/sign-in' and 'password reset with MFA' using our out of the box user flows. Custom policies are meant for complex scenarios.

Here is the link to how you can use userflows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows

Comment: Before signup, we need to make a REST Call to validate data and then sign up. Also we need to provide user option to choose MFA method ,which is not supported in OOTB  Userflow

Comment: this link does not even contain the word username, let alone describe how to configure it.